# Unexplained duplicate REST API calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-livedata

I'm maintaining an Android app for a company I recently joined. A stubborn bug I'm looking into is that the main screen takes a long time to load all but the first time. The logcats reveal that the Api call it's using to load the data is being called multiple times.

I have looked into the following reasons so far:

1. Cyclic code that is observing the data and changing some variable that unintentionally triggers the data reload again. However, I ran the code in CPU profiler too and the data is flowing appropriately from parent to child fragments
2. Multiple fragment instances could be calling the API. I investigated this with log statements:

```
reportGroupVM.selectedReport.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    binding.tvTitle.text = it.title
    LogUtil.d("EnergyConsumptionFrag", this@EnergyConsumptionFragment.toString())
    energyConsumptionVM.getSpecificReport(it.entityLinkContainer?.self?.href)
})
```

and got fragments with different ids:

```
2023-09-22 21:27:21.180  6992-6992  EnergyConsumptionFrag   dev.packagename                      D  EnergyConsumptionFragment{49abc22} (ab026b8f-bfe8-4587-8d4b-d451e46bea13) id=0x7f0a0211 EnergyConsumptionFragment}
2023-09-22 21:27:21.195  6992-6992  EnergyConsumptionFrag   dev.packagename                      D  EnergyConsumptionFragment{b12d8ca} (7a6776a6-824a-45d6-af2c-8c17207c1a43) id=0x7f0a0211 EnergyConsumptionFragment}
2023-09-22 21:27:21.210  6992-6992  EnergyConsumptionFrag   dev.packagename                      D  EnergyConsumptionFragment{96a67d1} (6f4d5392-8971-4906-9af7-94b5bf9df8fb) id=0x7f0a0211 EnergyConsumptionFragment}
2023-09-22 21:27:21.225  6992-6992  EnergyConsumptionFrag   dev.packagename                      D  EnergyConsumptionFragment{ff4a010} (45c24f6f-3ed6-4a75-ab08-d46f08523775) id=0x7f0a0211 EnergyConsumptionFragment}
```

... and so on

The only place that's spawning that fragment is

```
    loadFragment(EnergyConsumptionFragment())
    
    private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    
        if (!fragment.isAdded) {
            transaction.add(R.id.layout_report, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        } else {
            //transaction.replace(R.id.layout_report, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        }
    
        transaction.commit()
    }


which seems correct.

What other possibilities can I look into? How should I go about debugging this issue?
```

Comment: I think the code of the view model would help a bit. Also how are you requesting view models since you are calling different ones in one place?

Answer (score 0):

Try using SingleLiveEvent instead of LiveData:

```
open class SingleLiveEvent<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

More info: https://abhiappmobiledeveloper.medium.com/android-singleliveevent-of-livedata-for-ui-event-35d0c58512da

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model trigger multiple events which is observed here:

```
reportGroupVM.selectedReport.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    binding.tvTitle.text = it.title
    LogUtil.d("EnergyConsumptionFrag", this@EnergyConsumptionFragment.toString())
    energyConsumptionVM.getSpecificReport(it.entityLinkContainer?.self?.href)
})
```

If this is a case, you have to investigate why does it happen. A quick workaround might be to introduce a flag which you setup when you have got a first update, it would prevent all consequential requests.

As a newcomer to this project I would also suggest to turn on `StrictMode` and enable `Canary Leaks` library.